# How to get the attachment from a mail received in SAP HCI

Tags: email, imap, pop3, sap-cpi

I need to get an attachment out of an email received through a POP3 or IMAP adapter and process it further. The problem is that what I get out of that mail adapter is only the message of the mail (no title, no attachment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attachment should be possible acc. to this: https://uacp2.hana.ondemand.com/doc/368c481cd6954bdfa5d0435479fd4eaf/Cloud/en-US/08af047a0c0145ab8742b946cff7bcd7.html

As you can read: To access the mail attributes, i. e. Subject, From or To, you have to set them manually as Allowed Headers in the Runtime Configuration tab page. This will add them to a Whitelist.

The headers must be set in a Content Modifier as message header. I'll guess before receiving or sending the mail.
e.g. Accept | Constant | Type java.lang.String | Text/Plain

other values possible instead of Text/Plain: 
Text/CSV
Text/HTML
Application/XML
Application/JSON
Application/Octet-Stream